# Login to Azure CLI from Azure PowerShell task in DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-releases

I have a set of small scripts written i PowerShell using the `Az` module that perform some maintenance tasks as part of a release pipeline in Azure DevOps. One of these scripts use the Azure CLI for one of its operations so I need to authenticate with both Azure PowerShell and Azure CLI in the same devops task in my pipeline.

I know I can split up the script and run one section from an Azure CLI task and another from an Azure PowerShell task, but I was hoping to keep it all clean and together. I prefer the clarity and tooling when using Az-PowerShell, but since there is not yet parity between az-cli and az-powershell I sometimes need to use the former.

I may also be able to read env vars from an Azure CLI task and transfer them to PowerShell to do `az login` from there, but I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this. Ideally an `AzureCLIAndPowerShell` task or something like that.

Is there some way to perform a headless `az login` on a Microsoft hosted agent from within a script launched by an `Azure PowerShell` task?

Or to be more precise: Is there a way to use both Az-Powershell and Azure-CLI in an authenticated state within the same task in an Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

So here is what I have done.
This I have tested so switch to an Azure@CLI2 and this should get you access to both
To authenticate via azure powershell from CLI
Connect-AzAccount -KeyVaultAccessToken $(az account get-access-token --resource https://vault.azure.net --query accessToken --output tsv)  -AccessToken $(az account get-access-token --query accessToken --output tsv) -AccountId $userId["value"]

If you want to read KV data -KeyVaultAccessToken is required.

You can reverse this some and get an access token from azure PowerShell, but I have not found a way to use it to login.
In Azure PowerShell you can run
(Get-AzAccessToken).Token
That will give you the access Token. You might be able to do some tickery with it, but right now The easist method I would say is use the Azure@CLI2 pass in the servicePrincipal like normal and then use the above azure cli to Azure PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Ron. This is a pretty cool approach. I did not know I could extract tokens like that. As a test I grabbed the generic token using `az account get-access-token --query accessToken --output tsv` and used it with `Connect-AzAccount -AccessToken` and that appears to have worked. I needed the user id from `az account show --query user.name --output tsv` as well, but that seems to work!